# IIS URL Rewrite with Ajax Call Method

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-ajax

I have issue with url Rewrite and ajax request.

here's my config for URL Rewrite:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>        
                <rule name="RewriteASPX" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                       </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
                </rule>
        </rules> 
    </rewrite>
```

it works with this URL

https://www.example.com/section?data=data
or
https://www.example.com/section

but unfortunately, I have ajax request on my code :

https://www.example.com/section/method

the rule always rewrite the method to be https://www.example.com/section/method.aspx

here's my ajax request script

```
<script>
                debugger
                var phone = $('#<%=hidPhoneNO.ClientID %>').val();
                var check = $('#<%=hidCheckOutID.ClientID %>').val();
                var data = $('#<%=hidData.ClientID %>').val();
                var fails = "/Failed?Data=".concat(data)
                var suc = "/Success?Data=".concat(data)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ CheckOutID: check, PhoneNo: phone }),
                    url: "Section/Method",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function (data) {
                        var json = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                        /* alert(json["d"]);*/
                        if (json["d"] === "00") { location.href = fails }
                        else { location.href = suc }
                    },
                });
            </script>
```

is there any work around to keep the re-write function and done the ajax method call ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in rewrite rules to exclude specific path: `Section/Method`

`<match url="(.*)" />` changed to `<match url="^(?!.*section/method).*" />`

When the requested URL is `https://www.example.com/section/method`, it will not follow this rule, the request will not be rewritten.